# Can't find project classes/methods in test project

Tags: c#, visual-studio, nunit

In my namespace `Draughts` I have two projects, `Draughts` and `Draughts.UnitTests`. When I try to access `Draughts` methods/classes in `Draughts.UnitTests` it can't find anything at all. At the top of `Draughts.UnitTests` I put `using Draughts`. Any ideas?

BoardUnitTests.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Draughts;
using NUnit.Framework;

namespace Draughts.UnitTests
{
    public class BoardUnitTests
    {
        private Board GetBoard()
        {
            return true;
        }

        [Test]
        public void CheckValidBoardPosition_ValidPosition_ReturnsTrue()
        {
            Assert.AreEqual(1, 1);
        }
    }
}
```

In the code above it can't recognize Board which is a class I have defined in `Draughts`.

Here's a screenshot of my solution explorer:

[image]

Comment: does `Draughts.UnitTests` have a reference to `Draughts`?

Comment: Note that a `using` directive is _bot_ the same as a [reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wkze6zky.aspx).

Comment: This was my problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1211707/how-to-access-classes-in-another-assembly-for-unit-testing-purposes

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Probably this is related to one of these things

1. You don't have a reference to `Draughts` on your unit test project. Right click on the test project, then Add > Reference and select the project being tested.
2. Classes on `Draughts` are not public so you can't see them outside the project they belongs to

Comment: Did not know you had to explicitly add a reference through Add > Reference in solution explorer. Thanks.

Comment: #1 here will be the answer 9 out of 10 times. Note that you can break an existing project reference simply by removing the project temporarily and then adding it back in. I highly recommend people read this to know what is going on behind the scenes: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/managing-references-in-a-project?view=vs-2022#project-to-project-references

Comment: Also make sure to compile the test project after adding the reference

Answer (score 11):

I realize this is pretty old, but I came across this question while looking for a solution to my issue.  For me it turned out that my Test project and the Tested project were on two different versions of the .NET Framework.  I updated one, but forgot the other. Once I updated the test project to match the tested, everything worked like it should

Hope this helps the next person!  :)

Answer (score 1):

I ran into a similar issue as I used dotnet cli to create a test project and .net core project. I forgot to add the test project to my solution (right click solution > add > existing project). Once I did that, everything worked. Not the answer for OP but leaving it here in hopes it might help other people in future.

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was because I had them compiling on different versions of .net