# Regarding OOPS & Private class

Tags: c#, oop

if my class is private and constructor is public then what will happen. can i create a instance of that class or other class can i extend? i just need to know why and when people create a private class with public ctor?

the code like

```
private class LazyResource
{
    SomeBigResource _heavyObject = null;

    public SomeBigResource LazyLoad
    {
        get
        {
            if (_heavyObject == null)
                _heavyObject = new SomeBigResource();
            return _heavyObject;
        }
    }
}
```

plzz guide me thanks

Comment: Yeah realized that about 3 seconds after commenting, thus the delete. *shamefaced*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't create a non-nested private class in C#.

This is almost certainly a nested class, in which case only the containing type can instantiate an instance of it. And if `LazyResource` only had a private constructor then nothing would be able to instantiate it (except for a static member of `LazyResource` itself).

Comment: "only had a private constructor then nothing would be able to instantiate it".  Unless it had a public static member that gives you an instance of the class, as some implementations of the Singleton pattern do.

Comment: @mbeckish: True, I suppose in that case *something* would be instantiating it (ie, itself). Edited to clarify...

Comment: how to create the property LazyLoad?

Comment: I guess the containing class would have a private member -- something like `LazyResource lazyField = new LazyResource();` -- and then elsewhere your code could do something like `SomeBigResource bigResource = lazyField.LazyLoad;`. It's not the neatest way to implement a lazy-loading pattern, but it'll work. (Also note that .NET4 has the [`Lazy<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd642331.aspx) type which handles all this stuff for you.)