# Whats the difference between "Class" and "Private Class" declaration in C#?

Tags: c#

Whats the difference between "Class" only and "Private Class" declaration in C#?

Comment: Possible dupe: http://stackoverflow.com/q/3235283/1563422

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If these are *nested* classes, there's no difference:

```
namespace Foo
{
    public class Outer
    {
        private class ExplicitlyPrivate {}

        class ImplicitlyPrivate {}
    }
}
```

Type members always default to being private.

If it's a *top-level* class, then you *can't* make it private - but the default is internal:

```
namespace Foo
{
    class ClassIsInternalByDefault {}
}
```

Answer (score 4):

When you declare a class without specifying an accessibility modifier it will default to the lowest accessibility possible.

More practically, specifying private when private is not permissible can result in a compilation error.

Answer (score 1):

A simple answer is to say that a private class is meant to protect attributes within that class from being changed by any external classes, other than during construction of the program. A normal "class", well, doesn't have that protection.

It is a form of **ENCAPSULATION**.