# How to call a class in Mvc action if a class within the another class

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Here i write some class in another class but when i try to access the class why i'm not able to getting that class

```
namespace ImageWithallCtrls.Models
{
    public class GeneralAssClass
    {
         public class AccessClass2 :BaseAccessClass
         {
             private GeneralAssClass GenAss;
             public string L_Name { get; set; }

         }
         public class AccessClass1 : BaseAccessClass
         {
             public string Middle_Name { get; set; }
             public string Gender { get; set; }
         }
    }
}
```

**Home.cs**

```
public ActionResult AbsAssClass(GeneralAssClass GenAss)
{  
    Access1 ass1 = new Access1()
    {
        F_Name = GenAss. // HereI'im getting Equal, GetHash, Gettype, Tostring why not my class names("AccessClass2 ","AccessClass1")
    };
    Access2 ass2 = new Access2()
    {

    };
    return View();
}
```

Comment: `AccessClass1` and `AccessClass2` are classes, not properties or methods of `GeneralAssClass`. What are you trying to do here?

Comment: i  wana to Implement AccessClass1  And AccessClass2 in my Controler Action Here BaseAccessClass is my Abstract Calss

Comment: `GeneralAssClass.AccessClass1 myclass = new GeneralAssClass.AccessClass1();`

Comment: But your `GeneralAssClass GenAss` parameter makes no sense - the `GeneralAssClass` does not have any properties

Comment: do u have any altranate solutions for implementing that

Comment: For implementing what?

Comment: @DavidFunny your question is completely unclear.

Comment: @DavidFunny StackOverflow has a great article on how to ask good questions: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask There's a lot of detail missing including what your actual question is and what you've already researched/tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's two issues here.

Firstly you seem to be misusing inner classes.

Inner classes should only ever be used inside the outer class that declares them, so they should always be private.

[Why/when should you use nested classes in .net? Or shouldn't you?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48879/310988)

If you want the class to be accessible outside of the outer class then it should be a normal class, and not an inner class.

Secondly you're misusing the [object initialisation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384062.aspx) syntax.

> Object initializers let you assign values to any accessible fields or properties of an object at creation time without having to invoke a constructor followed by lines of assignment statements.

```
Access1 ass1 = new Access1()
{
    F_Name = GenAss. // HereI'im getting Equal, GetHash, Gettype, Tostring why not my class names("AccessClass2 ","AccessClass1")
};
```

The bit between the braces, { and }, allows you to set the fields and properties on the ass1 instance.

It's the same as writing:

```
Access1 ass1 = new Access1();
ass1.F_Name = GenAss. // HereI'im getting Equal, GetHash, Gettype, Tostring why not my class names("AccessClass2 ","AccessClass1")
```

`GenAss` doesn't exist in this scope, so you can't access it.

To fix this mess you should read up on the features you're using, research the best practices for them, and then restructure your code so that it follows those best practices, and most importantly ... works!